# How can I validate lat and long within one text input with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to validate the lat and long coordinates within the United States. The user is able to move an arrow to the location they want on a map and then it pulls up the lat/long, but if it's not exact the user can update the lat/long. I want to create a validation so users don't try to add a new location outside of the United States.

```
latlong = $('input[name="latLonNew"]').val();

function validateNewPlantsForm(){
  var a = latlong;
   if(isNaN(a) || a < -127 || a > 75){
      alert("Lat/Long not vaild.");
      return;
   }
 }
```

This always throws the error at me. How can I validate 2 numbers within 1 input text? For example this is what the value in the text box looks like when they pull up the location from the arrow: 39.7867, -105.1258.

Comment: `validateNewPlantsForm($('input[name="latLonNew"]').val())` and add `function validateNewPlantsForm(latlong)`

Comment: I have a function already, as you can see. So just add the latlong within the function ()'s ?..

Comment: down voting this makes no sense.. at least have the decency to explain why you're down voting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the latitude and longitude are coming together in one text field, we can make an assumption they are comma separated. If so, we can split on a comma and loop through each value to check the bounds.

```
function validateNewPlantsForm(latlng){
  var latlngArray = latlng.split(",");
  for(var i = 0; i < latlngArray.length; i++) {
    if(isNaN(latlngArray[i]) || latlngArray[i] < -127 || latlngArray[i] > 75){
      alert("Lat/Long not vaild.");
      return;
    }
  }
}

var latlng = $('input[name="latLonNew"]').val();
validateNewPlantsForm(latlng);
```